# django (but really python) curio about tuples

Tags: python, django, tuples

So i have a tuple:

```
SEX = [
    ("M","guy"),
    ("F","girl")
]
```

this is a django-thing, a tuple of 2-ples.

Next up, i have a string - `M`

Given that i have  `M` and i have the tuple as above, what is a function i can run that will quickly and efficiently return "guy"? (or really, retrieve the value "guy" from the `("M","guy") 2-ple above)
(i note this because i know how to do

```
def stackOverFlowAnswer(value):
    return "guy"
```

)

Do i have to loop over the entire tuple (yes yes, it is only 2 long. I'm just curious on this one), or is there a faster method to do this?

Comment: you actually have a list containing 2 tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a companion dictionary. Django can use the list, elsewhere you can use the dict.

```
SEX = [
    ("M","guy"),
    ("F","girl")
]
SEX_DICT = dict(SEX)
```

Comment: this - this is how to do it! thanks! django needs the tuple, and i need a dict (tee hee!) nice one, squire.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) instead of a list of tuples.

```
SEX = dict([
    ("M","guy"),
    ("F","girl")
])

print SEX['M']
```

You can also quickly identify if the input is valid (present within the dictionary):

```
val = "Z"
if val not in SEX:
    print "Invalid value"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not need this in your case, but in django, if this tuple is used as `choices` given to a field you can use the [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) function for an instance of that model to get the value, in your case, "guy" for "M".  Where `FOO` is the field name in lowercase.

So given this model:

```
SEX = [
    ("M","guy"),
    ("F","girl")
]
class SomeBody(models.Model):
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX)
```

in your view or template you can use `get_sex_display()` to obtain the "*display*" value.

```
people = SomeBody.objects.all()
for person in people:
    display_sex = person.get_sex_display()
    # do stuff to show the value...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write function to take parameter for `'M'` and `SEX`

```
for s in SEX:
     if s[0]== 'M':
         print s[1]
          #or return s[1]
```